# Ignoring return values from scipy in Python

Tags: python, scipy

when I'm calling SCIPY functions, I surely don't want to have to look up the documentation [*kidding*] but slightly more serious is that I don't want to have to accept all the return values. For example, I am calling FMIN_BFGS(). It has the option to return a bunch of values, I only want to keep the returned minimum. So I type

```
res = fmin_bfgs(...)
```

Dies with "too many values to unpack". I thought I had read that this would work

```
res, = fmin_bfgs(...)
```

but it gives the same error message. Finally what worked is to use answer of question #431866

```
res, _, _ , _ = fmin_bfgs(...)
```

But really? Do I have to check the documentation and count number of return values and use that many underscores or is there some more Pythonesque way to ignore everything returned except the first value.

Thanks, J.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  `res = fmin_bfgs(your_args_here)` should work just fine.

Comment: Consider using the much more nicely designed wrapper [minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your first example will work:

```
res = fmin_bfgs(...)
```

Then you can reference the values you're interested in with res[0].

In python 3 only, you could also do:

```
res, *_ = fmin_bgfs(...)
```

Which assigns the first value from the tuple to res, and the remaining values as a new tuple to _.

Answer (score 0):

Functions like this return a tuple of values.  The return statement looks something like

```
 return arr1, scalar2, label3
```

When this happens you have several options:

```
 mytuple = foo(...)    # accept the tuple
 print(len(mytuple))    # look at the number of items
 val1= mytuple[0]      # select the 1st item
```

Or you can use the tuple unpack option

```
 a, b, c = mytuple
 a, b, c = foo(...)
 a, _, _ = foo(...)     # _ is just a name for unimportant value
```

you can using the indexing right away

```
 a = foo(...)[0]
```

The

```
 a, = foo(...)
 a, = (12,)   # works
 a, = (12,12,12)  # unpacking error
```

only works when `foo` returns a single item tuple. It's most useful as a way of enforcing the 'rule' that this function returns that tuple count.  The left hand side `,` functions just like the right hand side one - designating a tuple.

So this is a basic Python issue - `how to unpack or select items from a tuple`.  It's not special to Scipy.

================

But a quick glance at `fmin_bfgs` indicates that I can get either one item (not tuple unpacking), 7 items if I ask for full output, or 8 if I ask for a further value.

Answer (score -1):

Dumb error on my part. What my code actually looked like was

```
res, l2e = fmin_bfgs(...)
```

except I had not defined res to be an array, like I should have done. So the interpreter thought I was giving a size=2 vector to populate the size=N answer back from fmin_bfgs. Once I define res=np.zeros(N) before the call then everything works fine.

Sorry to have wasted your time...

Comment: That should have had no effect at all.

Comment: The value of `res` before this call makes no difference in how this expression works.  This is an assignment, not a value insertion.